# Localhost and Android Connection

Tags: php, android, localhost

Let's say I'm developing application on my laptop. I have connection to the `localhost`, and created database. Will I be able to store, or extract data when I run my application on my phone? The phone is not connected to the laptop.

Comment: phone not connected to laptop is ok , but laptop and phone should be one same network i.e router etc then you can access the api's and database.

Comment: Your phone is its own localhost. Every device is its own localhost. Every device is localhost. Please reword your question.

Comment: @AbdulKawee i mean it is ok? if suppose i create user database in phone using php/msql it will store data in the phone when it is not connected to the    laptop

Answer (score 0):

Yes:
Your phone and laptop connected to same LAN (minimal example: set your phone as router with mobile hotspot and connect your development laptop to it).
In other words simply connect the phone and PC running the server to the same local network.
if you have puplic ip you can even let others test your app and connect to your pc as server (preferred static but dynamic will work as well but you have to monitor it and change it in your app every time it changes but most of the time it stays for hours if its not a moving mobile).
Edit:
For php apps you can install a php server in your android phone like Palapa Web Server (tested) and then in your app just make your calls to local address.

Comment: never to put your laptop in public network with public IP address, it's not that easy

Comment: it is too easy in most routers by using port forwarding if you have rooted android phone and your isp gives you public ip you can use an app for that i think its called PF or something.